# Check if any array item is not empty

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way in Kotlin without iterating through all the items to check if any array item is empty, meaning that it has "". Alternatively, if that is not possible, is there a way to tell if ALL items in the array are empty, meaning they all have "".

Comment: I dont think you can read any content of string without loading it first? there are lots of maps and styles to remove only empty items in kotlin tho

Comment: Assume that a function exists that you pass in an array that is already initialized. It could contain only empty strings or some items may have some text.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't tell how many element in an array are empty without visiting them. You can use `any` and `all`, both of which iterate internally though:

```
val withEmpty = arrayOf("", "a")
val allEmpty = arrayOf("", "")
println(withEmpty.any { it.isEmpty() }) //true
println(allEmpty.all { it.isEmpty() }) //true
```